# How can I test my svnadmin verify code?

Tags: svn, svnadmin

I'd like to start using `svnadmin verify` to verify that my svn hotcopies aren't corrupted.  My goal is to use a CRON job to run a verify nightly, and send myself an e-mail if there's a problem.  If there **isn't** a problem, I can see that the verify will return something of the form "* Verified revision 448." for each of the revisions.

However, to test my associated php code, I'd like to create a "problem" with one of the revisions (in a copy of my repository...) so that I can better understand what to look for.  My question is whether there's a way to intentionally corrupt one of my revisions for code testing purposes.  And, if there isn't, what message would I have received if a revision were corrupted?

Comment: I hope you're planning on doing this with a _copy_ of your repository. You know where the repository directory is located. Go under the `db/revs` and hack away. Delete a revision, or change the checksum on the bottom of a revision file. You can also just change the `db\format` file which is a pure text file. Change the first line to a higher number like 15 and see what happens. Just make sure you have a good backup. It's a great idea to test failures. See Netflix and their [chaos monkey](http://techblog.netflix.com/2012/07/chaos-monkey-released-into-wild.html).

Comment: Thanks for the Netflix link AND for the friendly reminder to do this with a copy of my repo. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly the easiest way to corrupt a repo is to delete part of it- go into the revs folder and delete a file in one of the subdirectories.

When you've run svnadmin you can restore the file of course. (or run on a local copy of your repo)

I would try this on both a revision and a property to see if you get different messages. Otherwise, the best place to ask is on the [SVN dev mailing list](http://subversion.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).